# How to register in each state (U.S.)

Tags: government, elections

I'm looking for a place that systematically keeps track of the ways voters in each state can register, such as whether they can register online or by mail, links, voter qualifications, etc.

Comment: I'm sad to see this is still unanswered, and I'm looking for any structured data in this direction.

Comment: It's probably possible to extract the information you want state by state, following each links "Find out how to register" on [this site](https://vote.gov/?1). Maybe a bit of scraping could do the job. You van also find [here](http://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/electronic-or-online-voter-registration.aspx) the list of states with online voters registration.

Answer (score 3):

[USA.gov](https://www.usa.gov/register-to-vote#item-212998) says

> No two states run their elections exactly the same, so contacting your
>   state  or local election office is the best way to find out about your
>   state’s unique election rules.

They provided links to connect to the 
[state election offices](https://www.usa.gov/election-office)
but these are just pointers to the > 50 sites. These sites do not have consistent formatting, so while this is a useful resource, it still involves a lot of work.